# Display and Save image in JTextPane

Tags: java, jtextpane, imageicon, htmleditorkit

I need to write an Editor like Word. It need to support edit file, insert and remove image and some other things.
I choose JTextPane to do such things.
I load and show image using imageIcon like this way:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
insertIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

And the problem I am facing now is how to save the image into file? I use HTMLDocument and HTMLEditorKit to implement the save method, the main logic is as below:

```
public void saveAs() {
    doc = (HTMLDocument) getStyledDocument();
    File newFile = new File(path);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile);
    kit.write(fw, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
    fw.close();
}
```

Kit and doc are private members in my Page class (Page derived from JTextPane).
And after the `saveAs` method excuted, the file saved doesn't including the image:

```
<html>
   <head>

  </head>
   <body>
     <p style="margin-top: 0">
      hello world
     </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
       <p $ename="icon">
    </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

From the HTML file we can see that the `image path` are not coded into there, I wonder how can I implement the `saveAs` method to support saving image?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Icon you inserted is not part of HTML so it's not saved. To do it in HTML style you need to insert `<IMG>` tag with reference to the image URL.

Could be `file://... some path here ... yourImage.jpg`

If you need to embed image somehow HTMLEditorKit is not enough.

There is no simple way to embed image.

You can see my attempt to do this [in RTF](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html)

But in general you should write the code yourself.